# Find the max mile reference for each corridor within dataset

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to find the maximum milage corridor segment for each corridor in the dataset. I used this very similar query to find the minimum milage, or first segment on a corridor in the increasing direction and this worked fine:

```
select distinct t.corridor_code_rb,t.frfpost,t.trfpost
from SEC_SEGMENTS t
where t.dir = 'I' and t.lane = 1
and t.frfpost = (select min(s.frfpost) from SEC_SEGMENTS s)
order by 1,2
```

However the problem arises when I try to use a similar query to find the max (last segment in the increasing direction) corridor length with the following query:

```
select distinct t.corridor_code_rb,t.frfpost,t.trfpost
from SEC_SEGMENTS t
where t.dir = 'I' and t.lane = 1
and t.trfpost = (select max(s.trfpost) from SEC_SEGMENTS s)
group by t.corridor_code_rb,t.frfpost,t.trfpost
```

What happens when I run this query is it only outputs the highest milage segment for the first corridor, then stops. Whereas with the lowest milage query, it returns that output for every corridor which is what I want. The frfpost is the beginning mile for each section and the trfpost is the ending milage. So frfpost is 'from reference post' and trfpost is 'to reference post'. Each corridor is broken up into segments between 5 and 40 miles in length usually between junctions with other corridors. Im trying to find the last segments for each corridor so that's where the issue lies.

Comment: What's your DBMS? Does it support RANK?

Comment: I use pl-sql developer. I not sure about rank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `group by` corridor_code_rb as well, to get the `max` value for that column per corridor_code_rb. Then `join` it to the main table.

```
select t.corridor_code_rb,t.frfpost,t.trfpost
from SEC_SEGMENTS t
join (select corridor_code_rb, max(s.trfpost) as trfpost from SEC_SEGMENTS 
      group by corridor_code_rb) s
on t.trfpost = s.trfpost
where t.dir = 'I' and t.lane = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you seem to use Oracle, which supports Analytical Functions:

```
Select corridor_code_rb, frfpost, tropfst
from
 (
   select corridor_code_rb, frfpost, trfpost,
      ROW_NUMBER()                        -- rank the rows
      OVER (PARTITION BY corridor_code_rb -- for each corridor
            ORDER BY trfpost DESC) AS rn  -- by descending direction
   from SEC_SEGMENTS t
   where t.dir = 'I' and t.lane = 1
 ) dt
WHERE rn = 1  -- filter the last row
```